# pandas data rows part merge

Tags: python, pandas

I have created a dataframe with pandas.
There are more than 1000 rows
I want to merge rows of overlapping columns among them.

For convenience, there are example screenshots made in Excel.
I want to make that form in PYTHON.

I want to make the above data like below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be as simple as setting the index.

`df = df.set_index('Symbol', append=True).swaplevel(0,1)`

Output should be as desired.